# What is the dimension of $c_0/M$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $c_0=\{ (x_n) : x_n\in \Bbb{R}, x_n \to 0\}$ and $M=\{(x_n)\in c_0 : x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_{10}=0\}$. Then, what is dim($c_0/M$) ?

Answer (score 2):

From the short exact sequence
$$ 0\to M\to c_0\to \Bbb R\to 0$$
where $c_0\to \Bbb R$ is $(x_n)\mapsto 1_1+\ldots+x_{10}$ we see that $c_0/M\cong \Bbb R$ so that $\dim c_0/M=1$.