# If $W = \{ (y_{n}) \in c_{0} : \ y_{1}+y_{2}+y_{3}=0\}$ what is $\operatorname{dim}(c_{0}/W)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $c_{0}$ be the space of sequences which converge to $0$. Let $W$ be a subspace of $c_{0}$ defined as

$$W =\bigl\{ \{y_{n}\} \in c_{0} : \ y_{1}+y_{2}+y_{3}=0\bigr\}$$ How does one calculate the  $\operatorname{dim}(c_{0}/W)$?

My attempts:

- We know that $\operatorname{dim}(c_{0}/W) = \operatorname{dim}(c_{0})-\operatorname{dim}(W)$
- Now given a $y=\{y_{n}\}$ in $c_{0}$ I can map it to a sequence in $W$ by defining $z_{n}=0$ for $n=1,2,3$ and $z_{n}=y_{n-3}$ for $n \geq 4$. This is acutally a $1-1$ map.
- Thinking along these lines somehow i feel that if $\beta=\{(x_{n}) \ : n \in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a basis for $c_{0}$, then I can map it $\beta'= \{(x_{n})' \ : \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ where I can map the each basis element of $W$ in the above manner.

Comment: The first attempt won't work because $c_0$ is infinite dimensional

Comment: You can have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643595/what-is-the-dimension-of-c-0-m).

Comment: Or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644823/c-o-x-nx-n-in-r-x-n-rightarrow-0-and-m-x-nx-n-in-c-0-x/1644833#1644833)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** A very quick approach is to use the first isomorphism theorem.  That is, if there is a space $Y$ an onto map $\phi: c_0 \to Y$ for which $\ker \phi = M$, then we must have
$$
c_0/M \cong Y
$$